# ¿Hay algún error en el código de este generador aleatorio?

Tags: java

veréis, estoy desarrollando un programa en Java que le pones diferentes nombres y te da uno aleatorio, yo no sé encontrar ningún error pero en la consola me sale esto:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at Packageprincipal.Main.main(Main.java:32)**

Os dejo el código:

```
package Packageprincipal;

import java.util.Scanner; public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Dime el número de personas/objetos para randomizar");
    int numeroarandomizar=scan.nextInt();
    switch(numeroarandomizar){
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Introduce el primer nombre");

        String nombre1=scan.next();

        System.out.println("Introduce el segundo nombre");

        String nombre2=scan.next();

        for(int i=0; i<1; i++){

            String personas[]=new String[2];
            personas[0]=null;
            personas[1]=nombre1;
            personas[2]=nombre2;

            int aleatorio=(int)Math.floor(Math.random()*(1-2)+2);
            System.out.println(personas[aleatorio]);

            }

        break;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Debes cerciorarte que **aleatorio** sea un número comprendido del valor mínimo del arreglo hasta el máximo; de la forma que generas el valor de dicha variable te sugiero la revises *(en ejemplos encontrados al leer su significado vi que la interpretaste mal)*; usa **System.out.println** para que se imprima cada valor **aleatorio** y mires cuando falla.

Comment: @RobertoLeónOramas El error no está allí...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un `IndexOutOfBound` es una excepción que se lanza cuando intentas acceder a un elemento que no existe.

Un array con 2 elementos (`String personas[]=new String[2];`) tiene 2 elementos; el elemento `0` y el elemento `1`). Si intentas acceder al elemento `2` (`personas[2]=nombre2;`) te lanza esta excepción.

NOTA 1: En el futuro, indica en que línea se produce el error. Si no ayudas a que la gente vea donde está el fallo, no te podrá ayudar.

NOTA 2: Tu "generador de números aleatorios" no hace lo que tú crees. Hay muchos ejemplos por internet sobre como hacerlo.

Comment: Gracias, un fallo tonto. Aunque mi generador aleatorio sí hace lo que yo creo.

Comment: Yo creo que no... https://ideone.com/YC8nJL

Comment: Hombre, me refería a que lo hace con algún cambiecito que le he hecho